# Remove /drupal from url path

Tags: drupal, url-rewriting

I'm working on a Drupal website, in which I want to display my website as www.ex.com instead ex.com/drupal

I have tried using this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^202.158.43.33$ [NC]

RewriteRule .* 202.158.43.33 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ drupal/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/drupal%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* drupal/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
RewriteRule .* drupal/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

which is saved in root folder and I have changed the $base_url = 'http://www.ex.com'; in drupal/sites/default/settings.php

When I run my website, I see the url as: 202.158.43.33/202.158.43.33/202.158.43.33/202.158.43.33.........

Could someone tell me how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing your own code, use Drupal's default .htaccess file. Then uncomment the last two lines of this snippet of code.

```
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Virtual host file Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/http/mysite.com"
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The document root should point to the Drupal you're navigating to under your current site, the "/drupal" subdirectory.

Comment: I still experience the same problem. what I wanted is not to display /drupal folder name in the URL. Say www.website.com/drupal I want to show it as www.website.com

Comment: So that's a different issue entirely. If your site is located at www.x.com/some_directory your virtual host is the problem not your .htaccess file. I'll add an edit to my answer with what your vhost should look like.

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested, still I couldnt resolve the problem. This is what I wanted, if I enter my website Ip say 202.158.43.33 it is redirecting me to 202.158.43.33/drupal I dont want to show /drupal in url

Comment: If your vhost and .htaccess are written as I have it listed above your home page must be set to "/drupal" just change this in the site information config page to whatever you want it to be. If you have done these three things it will fix your issue. If it doesn't fix your issue your not doing them correctly. Make sure your DocumentRoot points to the actual drupal install. This means if you follow the path in that document root you will see a directory with sites, modules, readme.txt, robots.txt and all that jazz in it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me but one last thing. I can see my url with IP address, I cannot see the drupal template or any of pictures as before.

Answer (score 0):

Do you NEED drupal files to be on separate folder in this domain? I'm just asking because there is the obvious answer to make one's drupal site run in root directory: Just move all files from drupal folder (all the files that are located into "drupal" folder) to the parent (root) directory and your site will display on  www.yourdomain.com, rather than on www.yourdomain.com/drupal